# How to get datetime.now format into this datetime fomat? C#

Tags: c#, silverlight, datetime

Im trying to have an app which finds the shortest time I have tried for a bit to get the datetime.now format into this example format which my code uses:

```
Comparetime.Add(new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 3, 29, 0));
```

I need the Datetime.Now code be in this string format. I have tried with a similar string:

```
testbox.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("YYYY-MMM-DD hh:mm:ss TT");
```

But that fails to produce the same format as (2000, 1, 1, 3, 29, 0)

Comment: Maybe help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

testbox.Text = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");

Only the month designator should be capitalized.

Comment: How would you convert to string? I tried but it tells me Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Answer (score 0):

GetDatTimeFormats() gets a string[] of the formats. Choose the one you want.

I guess this is wat you are looking for:

```
string[] listOfAvbDateTimeFormats = DateTime.UtcNow.GetDateTimeFormats();
string dateTimeFormatted = Convert.ToString(listOfAvbDateTimeFormats[92]);
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you use following format
string s = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");

it gives you string like: "2013-08-29 06:16:18 PM"

however, if you use 'MMM' in the above format, it gives you month as a word.

string s = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
"2013-Aug-29 06:16:59 PM"

Comment: Tells me:Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.DateTime'

Comment: Here DateTime is being converted to string not string into DateTime.. and the above line is working fine for me. Could you give me the line where you are getting error..

Comment: Turns out it can't be a string as I have to use ticks any ideas? to get current time so it can be subtracted using the code in the first post?